# Is it possible to add a counter in a dataframe which counts per row and resets to 1 when a value in one of two columns is changed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, reset

I have a dataframe in which I need to create a counter in a new column. The counter should start counting per row. The counter needs to reset to 1 when the value of one of two columns in the dataframe changes. The values in the columns are integers.

DataFrame example:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'Col1':[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4 ], 'Col2':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I tried this initially, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
df['Counter'] = df.groupby((df['Col1'] != df['Col1'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
df['Counter'] = df.groupby((df['Col2'] != df['Col2'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
print(df)
```

Desired result:

```
result = {'Col1':[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4 ], 'Col2':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] ,'Counter':[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]}
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(result)
```

I really hope somebody knows how to do this. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: show us what you have done so far...

Comment: @Yohst I added an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Counter'] = df.groupby(( (df['Col1'] != df['Col1'].shift(1)) | (df['Col2'] != df['Col2'].shift(1)) ).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
```